# Question About Central Limit Theorem

Tags: probability, statistics, central-limit-theorem

When I google the central limit theorem it says the following: The central limit theorem states that if you have a population with mean $μ$ and standard deviation $σ$ and take sufficiently large random samples from the population with replacement, then the distribution of the **sample means** will be approximately normally distributed.

My question is the following: does the central limit theorem **only** apply to sampling distributions of the sample mean? Or can it apply to **any** sampling distribution of any statistic? Such as sample variance, sample proportion, or difference between two sample means, etc..

Thank You For Your Time

Comment: The general philosophy of CLT is that, if you have random variables $X_1, X_2, \dots, X_n$ which are (1) "small" in certain cense, and (2) are "almost independent", then their sum $S_n=X_1+\cdots+X_n$ will behave like a normal distribution. So anything that can be viewed in this sense may have chances to be a subject of CLT.

Comment: So something like sample variance will also have a sampling distribution that is normally distributed if n is large correct? So CLT applies to sampling distributions of ANY statistic in general. Not just sampling distributions of the sample mean yes?

Comment: I have little acquaintance with statistic used in statistics, so let me not make any general comment about it. However, it is indeed true that [CLT also holds for sample variance](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/105337/186927) assuming finite 4th moment.

Answer (score 2):

The Central Limit Theorem does not apply to the sampling distribution of all statistics, not even those involving the sample means.

Here is a counterexample. Let $X_1,\dots ,X_n \sim_{i.i.d.} F_X$ and let $Y_1,\dots, Y_m  \sim_{i.i.d.} F_Y$, independent of the $X_i$.  Let the statistic be $\hat \theta = \sum_{i=1}^n X_i/n - \sum_{j=1}^m Y_j/m$. Suppose $n\rightarrow \infty$, but $m$ is fixed.  Then the distribution of $$\frac{\hat \theta -E(\hat \theta)}{Var^{1/2}(\hat \theta)}$$ does not converge to $N(0,1)$ or any other normal distribution.

Comment: Why the downvote?